# Need help identifying this tree located near Tampa Florida

Tags: identification, trees

I am looking to see if the tree pictured will be a good fit in my landscape and need help identifying it first. Thanks in advance!

[image]

[image]

Comment: You may need to wait until there are berries or seeds for more clues.

Comment: If you have no luck here, you might want to take the tree photos to a reputable local plant nursery and see if they can identify it.

Comment: Maybe Google for tree ID sites?  Here's the first one I found. https://floridahikes.com/florida-plants-and-trees

Comment: Crush a leaf, see if it is a Laurel.